# How to fix page does not loading images untill page is scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, image, jquery-ui

I load the page when i scroll down a page then it shows a picture in the tab.
https://www.nuvatus.com/brands/

Comment: we cannot see the brands page. It is redirecting to wp-admin page.

Comment: When you scroll down a page below the tabs on mobile it's load or show tab pictures only then can anyone expert tell me how to fix it?? The site is password protected if anyone will do please tell me in comment i will remove restriction

Comment: like @Vel said, we can only see wordpresses login page, not the page you want us to take a look at, we can't debug any problems without access or any code provided

Comment: wait dear just a minute

Comment: please check now

Comment: thanks to all i have fix it by myself!